# Access Authenticated User's information in Django Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-storage

I was wondering how can we access a user's data in another model? For example here is my current situation.

- A user has a foreignKey to a company; so a user is associated to a company.
- I have implemented a file upload page. This page uses a custom storage solution, that uploads the file to Amazon S3. (It is based of S3BotoStorage).
- Within this constructor, I want to access the bucket_name that is associated to this company, where the company is linked to the user. All my users will have to be logged in to use the upload page.
- So: logged in User has foreignKey to Company, and Company has bucket_name. Logged in user is on file upload page.

This is the view:

```
class PictureCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Picture

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PictureCreateView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    def form_valid(self, form):    
        self.object = form.save()
        self.request.FILES.get('file')
        data = [{'name': f.name, 'url': settings.MEDIA_URL + "pictures/" + f.name.replace(" ", "_"), 'thumbnail_url': settings.MEDIA_URL + "pictures/" + f.name.replace(" ", "_"), 'delete_url': reverse('upload-delete', args=[self.object.id]), 'delete_type': "DELETE"}]
        response = JSONResponse(data, {}, response_mimetype(self.request))
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=files.json'
        return response
```

This is the Picture Model (File Model or whatever)

```
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage as s3_storage

class Picture(models.Model):

    def custom_upload_to(instance, filename):
        return 'pictures/' + filename        

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Picture, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    file = models.FileField(storage=s3_storage,upload_to=custom_upload_to)
```

---

This is the storage model that I set as my default_storage in settings.py:

```
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage

class customStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['bucket'] = ***HERE-I-WANT-TO-GET-COMPANY'S-BUCKET***
        super(customStorage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

From the from or template, can I pass it has an argument and retrieve it later? Can I retrieve this information within the model directly? Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks!

EDIT: This has to do with users because the user will contain the ForeignKey to the company it is linked to, and that company will contain the Bucket in question...

EDIT #2: I just tried **self.object.user = self.request.user** in the form_save and it works, but how can I go beyond that and access the fields I added when I extended the User with a UserProfile class? For example:

```
self.object.user = self.request.user
self.company = self.object.user.company.bucket
```

So Company is a foreign_key within the User extended Profile, and company contains a bucket field.

Comment: I'm really confused. What does any of this have to do with users? You can get the current user from form_valid() with self.request.user. Is that what you're after?

Comment: See edit for more clarifications! Thanks

Comment: are you looking for `user.get_profile()`? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change User, so I assume your Foreign Key is on the Profile. You probably want to use self.request.user.[get_profile()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_profile).company.bucket. Make sure you've configured your profile module correctly by setting `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` in your settings.py